# In vb.net, is there a variable for other?

Tags: vb.net

```
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If TextBox1.Text = 123456 Then
            MsgBox("Activated")
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = 1234567 Then
            MsgBox("Activated2")

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I have an input box, and there are 2 combos that give you an msgbox, but how do I get it to read if the input is anything else?

Comment: I believe with Else-Block before End If?

Comment: Or a switch-case block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file. This will show you that you shouldn't check equality of a string against an integer.

[image]

You could change the integers to strings, or try to parse the string as an integer. It would be safer (less prone to exceptions) to just compare two strings.

```
If TextBox1.Text = "123456" Then
    MsgBox("Activated")
ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "1234567" Then
    MsgBox("Activated2")
```

Now for your question. I'd suggest using a `Select / Case` for readability and additional flexibility. It is my preference to use it when handling more than two cases.

```
Select Case TextBox1.Text
    Case "123456"
        MsgBox("Activated")
    Case "1234567"
        MsgBox("Activated2")
    Case Else
        MsgBox("Else")
End Select
```

One advantage is that you only need to evaluate TextBox1.Text once, which doesn't seem important for a string property, but if it were a function call or some property with something going on behind the scenes, you wouldn't necessarily want to invoke that twice. In the case of an `If / Else`, you'd want a temporary variable, in a `Select / Case` you don't need it (not to say it doesn't create one behind the scenes).

Another benefit is the shorthand for `>= AND <=`: you can check a range of values.

```
Case "1234567" To "12345678"
```

will cover all cases between these two strings, alphabetically.

Lastly, there is shorthand for `Or` as well

```
Case "1234567", "2222222"
```

will cover either of these situations in a single case.

Comment: Finally some mentions  the elephant in the room - Option Strict!

Comment: You weren't here yet; someone had to.

Answer (score 0):

```
If TextBox1.Text = 123456 Then
    MsgBox("Activated")
ElseIf TextBox1.Text = 1234567 Then
    MsgBox("Activated2")
Else
    MsgBox(TextBox1.Text)
End If
```